# Excel set value filters to two value filters

Tags: excel, filter, pivot

I have a set of data and my conditions are:
Column 1 begins with "000000"
Column 3 begins with "50" 
Column 4 count is less than "6" 
Column 5 sum is greater than "10000"

since there are count and sum columns i need two value filters (to be filtered again by count less than 6 and sum greater than 3) in the pivot table.

All examples lead to multiple filters by using 1 label filter and 1 value filter on the row head dropdown. But what if i want to filter my two value filters. No available answer in the net.

Please help.

Comment: You can create a calculated column that flags a cell as a value (like `TRUE`) and then filter on that. The formula would be something like `=AND(LEFT(A1,6)="000000",LEFT(C1,2)="50",D1<6,E1>10000)` - This will return `TRUE` if the conditions are met or `FALSE` if not. You can drag this down to get the value for each row, then you can then filter on `TRUE` and you should have what you need.

Comment: This might help... http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/10/22/more-than-one-filter-on-pivot-table-field/